# Count per type of a specific column in JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

I have the following model. `Posts` and `Reactions`.

Now I want to get a list of all posts and how often and how someone reacted to that post, i.e.

```
id | reaction | count
---+----------+------
 1 | like     | 13
 1 | dislike  | 1
 3 | like     | 89
```

So far what I go is this:

```
SELECT posts.id, reactions.reaction, COUNT(reactions.reaction)
   FROM posts JOIN reactions on posts.id = reactions.post_id
GROUP BY posts.id, reactions.reaction
```

But this only seems to counts and display the total reaction, what do I need to add so it gives the result per reaction type?

It would be even better, if it could just display the reaction count as columns, too. I.e.

```
id | lik | dislike
---+-----+------
 1 | 13  | 1
 3 | 89  | 0
```

I am still playing around with `crosstab` to get the gist of this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation with `case` expression

```
SELECT 
      p.id, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN r.reaction = 'like' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) like,
      SUM(CASE WHEN r.reaction = 'dislike' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) dislike
FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN reactions r on p.id = r.post_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Nice, is there also a generalized version?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you:

```
SELECT id, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN reaction = 'like' THEN Lik ELSE 0 END) [like],
      SUM(CASE WHEN reaction = 'dislike' THEN Dislike ELSE 0 END) dislike
FROM Reactions
GROUP BY id
```